# Why does call to api token during authentication fail in specific environment? (400 error)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, access-token, http-status-code-400

**Background/Problem**: I am running an Angular app (with C#/.NET WebApi/DataAccess) and am getting the following errors when attempting to login (happens in DEV environment, not in REL):

Chrome Dev Tools Console errors:

- POST http://localhost:1789/api/token 400 (Bad Request)
- Backend
  returned code 400, body was [object Object]

Error is only happening in DEV. Does not happen in REL or PROD. This was working in DEV previously.

**What I've tried so far**:

1. I am able to make calls to other classes and methods in the WebApi,
   but not sure where this error came from.
2. I don't see any extra discernible information in "Network" tab of
   Chrome Dev Tools (it just mentions the status code again)
3. I used the debugger in the Sources tab of Chrome dev tools and also
   did not see any extra discernible information
4. There have not been any changes in the C# code that I can see from
   source control. The Angular component and service are the same as
   well.
5. I have tested other parts of the API as mentioned above
6. I have checked my config files multiple times and they seem to have
   the appropriate values they used to have
7. I have looked up information about token authorization such as:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server
   [Spotify API bad request on api/token authorization Error: 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218678/spotify-api-bad-request-on-api-token-authorization-error-400)
   (as well as all the other SO articles on 400 error for api token I
   could find)
8. Debugged in Visual Studio: For OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions:
   *AccessTokenFormat* is null. *AuthorizeEndpointPath* is {}. But
   *TokenEndpointPath* is {/api/token}

**Code**:

**login.component.ts**:

```
cmdLogin_click()
{
    if (this._authForm.value.username != null && this._authForm.value.password != "")
    {
        if (this._authForm.valid)
        {
            this.securityService.loginEndpoint(this._authForm.value.username,this._authForm.value.password)
            .subscribe(response => {

                this.setUser(response);

                this.routerService.navigate(['/home']);
            },
        }
    }
}
```

**security.service.ts**:

```
public loginEndpoint(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let url = API_URL + '/api/token';
    let ip = "";
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    let content: string = "grant_type=password&username=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&ip=" + ip
    return this.http.post(url, content, { headers: headers }).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code. // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
        'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);


    // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(25),
        Provider = new EmdOAuthProvider(),
        RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
    };


    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

My expected result is to be able to login without the error. My actual result is the errors listed above.

Been stuck on this for hours. Where should I be focusing at this point?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I am having similar problems.

Comment: @HitLikeAHammer unfortunately I have not found one

Comment: I did actually find my issue, I was saving the ProtectedTicket in the database but the field was too small for some of the tickets (my problem was intermittent).  When it tried to deserialize, it failed.  I never got a DB error when trying to dave the value that was too large because the stored procedure just truncated it. I made the field a nvarchar(max) and the problem went away.