# Getting status 415 error when trying to request Spotify access token

Tags: react-native, axios, spotify

I am trying to acquire Spotify's Client Credentials Flow access token, but the following code just gives me status error 415. I am using React Native/axios.

```
    makeSPYReq = (id) => {

        axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', 
            { 
                data: { 
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                } 
            }, 
            { 
                headers: { 
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${id}`
                }
            })
            .then((res)=>console.log(res))
            .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const encodedString = new Buffer(`${SPY_CLIENT}:${SPY_SECRET}`).toString('base64');
        this.makeSPYReq(encodedString)
    }
```

I'm having issues trying to figure out where the error might be. I thought I did everything according to the doc: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow

Comment: Is this relatable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218678/spotify-api-bad-request-on-api-token-authorization-error-400. Do you execute this code on the client, then here is your answer I think

Comment: I think that's the problem. Thank you! Do you know how I could set the node server environment up for React Native just for this purpose?. Any tips or links would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never used react and I don't know how it works. Maybe you can setup a simple express server. An API to call from your front end? I am not sure. https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Cheers! I'll check it out.