# Cannot OAuth into Spotify API through CloudFlare Worker with Client Credentials Flow

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, fetch, spotify, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to get an Access Token from Spotify to use it further to access the Spotify API without need of redirect URL to an Auth confirm page.
I have a **CloudFlare Worker** setup that has the code for this but it keeps failing no matter what I try.
According to the Docs of the  [Client Credential Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) I'm supposed to make a POST Request to the Endpoint as follows:

```
const credentials = btoa(`${SPOTIFY_ID}:${SPOTIFY_SECRET}`);
const auth = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": `Basic ${credentials}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
  }),
});
```

In this example `SPOTIFY_ID` and `SPOTIFY_SECRET` are stored into the Environment Variables of the Worker itself and are valid credentials of my Spotify APP. The `btoa()` method converts the credentials into Base64 as requested under the format of **<cliend_id:client_secret>** and the output is correct (tested decoding it successfully)

The Response I get from the POST Request is always the same:

```
{
 "webSocket": null,
 "url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
 "redirected": false,
 "ok": false,
 "headers": {},
 "statusText": "Bad Request",
 "status": 400,
 "bodyUsed": false,
    "body": {
      "locked": false
    }
 }
```

Also tested to run the request with **curl** and everything works, it returns a valid token.
I saw on [other topic related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218678/spotify-api-bad-request-on-api-token-authorization-error-400) that this is supposed to be run server side because of the OAuth security convention, but the CloudFlare worker, even though runs on top of [V8](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/how-workers-works) should be considered server side as well, since it doesn't run in the browser.

I would like to understand better why it seems that CloudFlare Workers environment is considered client side, this also happens if I try to use the [Spotify API Client for Node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) where it doesn't include the server side methods while compiling, making them none existent in the compiled worker (maybe because of Webpack bundling?)

Another idea is that the `fetch()` method is client-side by default, so a possible solution would be to use another library to make the POST request to Spotify but on Workers I don't know which one can be used.

Am I missing something here? This has been taking too much time to solve and I have no hint.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the response body to see if there is a more detailed error message? Do `let text = await response.text()`, then look at the `text`. I doubt it has anything to do with "client-side" vs. "server-side" as a request from Workers is definitely server-side and Spotify wouldn't have any reason to think otherwise. I think the problem may actually be that you are sending content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but the actual content you are sending is JSON. Maybe you need to send "application/json" as the type?

Comment: @KentonVarda I think by response you're referring to the **auth** const in my code. The JSON that I posted below was the actual stringify of the auth object with all its content. There are no additional messages as far as I can tell

Comment: The `auth` variable in your code is a `Response` object, as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response This is NOT the data returned by the server, it is an object that encapsulates the HTTP response. You need to do `let text = await auth.text()` to read the actual content returned by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work but I have no clue how and why.
Basically by reading more on OAuth questions I figured out a bypass.
The problem seems to be the `body` parameter that might get in conflict with the `fetch()` method.

As Kenton mentioned I tried to look for more error info and eventually I came across this with the old code:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "grant_type parameter is missing"
}
```

This was not printed before I changed the `credentials` to be fully parsed into the const instead of evaluating it under the `Authorization` key of the `headers` object.

The way to make it work inside **CloudFlare Workers** is to `pass the body grant_type param as query string inside the URL` like this:

```
const credentials = `Basic ${btoa(`${SPOTIFY_ID}:${SPOTIFY_SECRET}`)}`
const auth = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Authorization: credentials,
  },
});
```

What I get now is the same correct response with token as worked in **curl**

```
{
  "access_token": "randomstringthatrepresentsmytokenifinallysolvedthisshitthanksgodiwasgoinginsane",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

If someone knows better why this works and the previous doesn't it's encouraged to comment to this message.

Comment: Again, I think the problem is that the content-type you sent to the server did not match the content. Your request body is `JSON.stringify({ grant_type: "client_credentials" })`, i.e. JSON, but the content-type you sent is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is different from JSON. Your fix works because you got rid of the body altogether and passed the grant_type in the URL instead. But I think if you made the body type and content match then that should also fix the problem.

Comment: I see your point, but due to the [API Docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) I need to send the Request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, what I don't get is whether the `fetch()` method is acting like this or if Spotify has mistaken the Docs, since they precise to send a Body with `grant_type: "client_credentials`

Comment: Hmm from my reading of the docs, it looks like they want the body to contain `grant_type=client_credentials` (which is what x-www-form-urlencoded looks like), whereas your code will send `{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}` (JSON).